# Bash filter files do not match a specific pattern

Tags: bash

In my bash script I need to loop a specific folder and exclude all the files that **not** contains a specific string, for example

```
. << current directory
db/abc.sql
db/def_something.sql
```

Should return just db/abc.sql

I'm able to loop the files that contains **something**, but I'm not able create the opposite, that return just db/abc.sql.

This, filter for **something**.. how I can list the files that **not contain something** ?

```
for file in ls ./db/*_something.sql;
do
  echo $file
done
```

As return I need the full path because need to execute some operation on the file content.

Comment: Btw.: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: I usually dont write bash script, i just see some usages of `ls` to to this.. i dont know if there is a better solution.. :) Maybe there is something more elegant to do this.. i dont know if is the right way (in both cases, filter or not filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
ls -1 $PWD/db/*.sql | grep -v "_something.sql$"
```

where $PWD enables to obtain the full path to the file, 'db' is your relative subdirectory, '*.sql' is the first filter which enables to remove filenames other than needed, e.g. *.txt, and `grep` with -v  enables to remove filenames of the specified pattern, here: ending with '_something.sql'.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for file in !(*something.sql); do echo ${file}; done;
```

Demo :

```
$ls -1
abc.sql
def_something.sql
$for file in !(*something.sql); do echo ${file}; done; 
abc.sql
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need loop for this.
You simply want to `find` all files except matching specific pattern, so:

```
$ find db -type f ! -name "*something.sql"
db/abc.sql
```

where:

- db : your path to search
- -type f : plain files (ommit directory in the results)
- '!' : negate next test
- -name "pattern" : obvious